# Pandas sort data frame with the class label unchanged

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I would like to sort each column of the data frame in ascending order

```
df:

           a          class
     0  0.726300       1
     1  0.330514       1
     2  0.261841       1
     3  0.321594      -1
     4  0.273200      -1
     5  0.125400       1

code:

for each_column in df.columns:
if each_column !='class':
    df[each_column] = sorted(df[each_column])

sorted  df:

           a          class
      0  0.125400      1
      1  0.261841      1
      2  0.273200      1
      3  0.321594     -1
      4  0.330514     -1
      5  0.726300      1
```

But I would want the class column with the corresponding input values as in the original data frame. For example in the original df, in the 4th row (i.e index = 4) the input value is 0.273200 and the corresponding class is -1,the input value 0.330514 and the corresponding class is 1,  but after sorting the df the class value got changed for the above mentioned values which should not happen. Please suggest me on how to tweak the code for the class column to be associated with the corresponding input value.

Answer (score 0):

[`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) should do the job:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
      a  class
0  0.726300      1
1  0.330514      1
2  0.261841      1
3  0.321594     -1
4  0.273200     -1
5  0.125400      1

In [6]: df.sort_values(by='a')
Out[6]: 
      a  class
5  0.125400      1
2  0.261841      1
4  0.273200     -1
3  0.321594     -1
1  0.330514      1
0  0.726300      1
```

Comment: @fuglede the solution you have given is returning the original data frame, it is not sorting.

Comment: @vikky: It returns a sorted `DataFrame`. You could overwrite `df` with that one if that's what you need.

Comment: @fuglede exactly, i want to override the df columns with the sorted values

Comment: Use `df.sort_values(by='a', inplace=True)`.